# Pass a Button value and Update the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Working on a personal project, one of the functions of the project is to update the user status on what event they are participating.

i wanted to submit a value using a button

```
 <form action="/users/fooddrivebanner" method="POST"><button name="fooddrive" type="submit" value="fooddrive" id="fooddrive">Participate</button></form>
```

then pass the value to my route and save it inside my database

```
router.post('/fooddrivebanner', (req,res)=>{
const { fooddrive } = req.body;
const _id = ObjectId(req.session.passport.user._id);
User.findOne({ _id: _id }).then((user)=>{
    if (!user) {
        req.flash("error_msg", "user not found");
        res.redirect("/fooddrivebanner");
      }
      if (typeof eventparticpating !== "undefined") {
        user.eventparticpating = 'fooddrive';
      }
      user.save(function (err, resolve) {
        if(err)
          console.log('db error', err)
           // saved!
         });
      
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here is the User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
eventparticpating: {
    type: String,
    default: 'None At The Moment'
}

});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

It showed a console error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'eventparticpating' of null
```

UPDATE
Edit 1:
I followed Mr Gambino instructions, error Gone yet cannot update the database, how would i be able to adjust and find my user?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving within the findOne function,you can do this:

```
router.post('/fooddrivebanner', async (req,res) => {
const { fooddrive } = req.body;
const _id = ObjectId(req.session.passport.user._id);
await User.findOne({ _id: _id }, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
        req.flash("error_msg", "user not found");
        res.redirect("/fooddrivebanner");
    }
}).updateOne({ eventparticpating: "foodrive" });
});
```

I hope that answers your question

Comment: It almost did, the typeerror value got fixed but it did not update the database record in the mongodb

Comment: What if you make it async and await

Comment: Is it able to find the user?

Comment: no actually, it gives a 'typeerror: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined' whenever it i run/load to try and make changes right now